# Adding PDF from stream while creating PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, html-to-pdf

I have to create a new PDF document, but I also have to attach existing PDF files to the new one.
It was easy enough to attach them at the end. But I have to attach these in the middle of the document so its easier to know which is related to which.

So, essentially it would look liked this:

New coverpage   (from html)
New invoicerow (from html)
old invoiceRow (from stream)
New invoicerow (from html)
old invoiceRow (from stream)

But the issue I am running into is that the file either doesn't accept adding the stream from the already existing PDF, which means I only get the new generated rows. Or one of the existing PDFs is all I am seeing.

The code I have so far, which works for generating the new rows like I want them (before adding the existing PDFs that is) looks like this:

```
private async Task<byte[]> CreateHtmlString(List<Invoice> invoices)
{
    byte[] bytes;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10F, 10F, 10F, 0F))
        {
            using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream))
            {
                pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
                if (!document.IsOpen())
                {
                    document.Open();
                }
                StringBuilder sbHeader = new StringBuilder();
                sbHeader.Append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                sbHeader.Append("<html>");
                sbHeader.Append("<body>");
                sbHeader.Append("<table style='table-layout: auto; width: 100%;'>");
                sbHeader.Append("<tr>");
                sbHeader.Append("</tr>");
                foreach (var invoice in invoices)
                {
                    sbHeader.Append("<tr>");
                    sbHeader.Append("</tr>");
                }
                sbHeader.Append("</table>");
                sbHeader.Append("</body>");
                sbHeader.Append("</html>");
                using (StringReader srHtml = new StringReader(sbHeader.ToString()))
                {
                    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(document);
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        htmlparser.Parse(srHtml);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var invoice in invoices)
                {
                    document.NewPage();
                    StringBuilder sbRow = new StringBuilder();
                    sbRow.Append("<div style='page-break-before:always'>&nbsp;</div>");
                    sbRow.Append("<table style='table-layout: auto; width: 100%;'>");
                    sbRow.Append("<tr>");
                    sbRow.Append("</tr>");
                    foreach (var acknowledgeJournal in invoice.AcknowledgementJournals)
                    {
                        sbRow.Append("<tr>");
                        sbRow.Append("</tr>");
                    }
                    sbRow.Append("</table>");
                    sbRow.Append("<table style='table-layout: auto; width: 100%;'>");
                    sbRow.Append("<tr>");
                    sbRow.Append("</tr>");
                    foreach (var invoiceItem in invoice.InvoiceItems)
                    {
                        sbRow.Append("<tr>");
                        sbRow.Append("</tr>");
                    }
                    sbRow.Append("</table>");
                    sbRow.Append("</body>");
                    sbRow.Append("</html>");
                    using (StringReader srHtml = new StringReader(sbRow.ToString()))
                    {
                        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(document);
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            htmlparser.Parse(srHtml);
                            foreach (var attachment in invoice.Attachments)
                            {
                                var retrievedAttachment = await getPdf();
                                retrievedAttachment.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Combined.pdf");
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
                return bytes;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it at all possible to do what I want to do this way? Or will I have to change it, and make one stream per page, and then merge them after creation?

Comment: You are aware that once the html has been converted to pdf, there is nothing in the pdf anymore that's in any way tagged as a table or table row? Thus, isolating an *old invoice row* in an existing pdf is not easy at all in general.

Comment: The old invoice row isn't a table row or something like that. It's a whole invoice as a pdf document (might have been unclear here). But I guess the issue is similar, in that I would have to add them all as separate streams to a list. And then go through that list to build the combined document

Comment: In that case create each part as a separate PDF in a `MemoryStream` and merge all of them using `PdfCopy`.